# java swing JTextField set PlaceHolder

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, placeholder

I created a JTextField and now I want to set the placeholder on that JTextField, but I don't know how? Please help. Here is my code:

```
JTextField database=new JTextField("Enter Data Base Name");
database.setPreferredSize(database.getPreferredSize());
database.setText("");
```

Comment: to avoiding (my probably) missinterpetations placeholder is "please input text" or Icon in the case that JTextField is empty ???

Comment: What do you mean exactly by placeholder? Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10507193/928711) can help you?

Comment: I wrote my own component. See here: https://github.com/CollinAlpert/APIs/blob/master/javax/swing/JTextBox.java

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this class:

```
package playground;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PlaceholderTextField extends JTextField {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final PlaceholderTextField tf = new PlaceholderTextField("");
        tf.setColumns(20);
        tf.setPlaceholder("All your base are belong to us!");
        final Font f = tf.getFont();
        tf.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), 30));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tf);
    }

    private String placeholder;

    public PlaceholderTextField() {
    }

    public PlaceholderTextField(
        final Document pDoc,
        final String pText,
        final int pColumns)
    {
        super(pDoc, pText, pColumns);
    }

    public PlaceholderTextField(final int pColumns) {
        super(pColumns);
    }

    public PlaceholderTextField(final String pText) {
        super(pText);
    }

    public PlaceholderTextField(final String pText, final int pColumns) {
        super(pText, pColumns);
    }

    public String getPlaceholder() {
        return placeholder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics pG) {
        super.paintComponent(pG);

        if (placeholder == null || placeholder.length() == 0 || getText().length() > 0) {
            return;
        }

        final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) pG;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(getDisabledTextColor());
        g.drawString(placeholder, getInsets().left, pG.getFontMetrics()
            .getMaxAscent() + getInsets().top);
    }

    public void setPlaceholder(final String s) {
        placeholder = s;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank's for a quick replay dear

Comment: I found the rendering of the placeholder text looked less than ideal. Based on [this SO answer about text rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537742/1348743), I added the static field:
`private static Map<?, ?> hints = (Map<?, ?>) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints");`
Then changed the line that sets the rendering hints to `if (hints != null) g.setRenderingHints(hints); else // set them directly as shown in the answer`

Answer (score 25):

```
JTextField searchText;
```

...

In constructor:

```
searchText = new JTextField("Search");
searchText.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
searchText.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if (searchText.getText().equals("Search")) {
            searchText.setText("");
            searchText.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if (searchText.getText().isEmpty()) {
            searchText.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            searchText.setText("Search");
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This answer can become much more useful by providing some context surrounding your code.

Comment: Of course, if you type in the text "Search" and then click back on the field that text will disappear.

Comment: i love this code , but the text is visible only after clicking the box, i have set the text before also to tackle this issue. Is there a better way ?

Comment: We just need to add  searchText.setText("..."); under searchText = new JTextField("Search");
searchText.setForeground(Color.GRAY);

Answer (score 11):

So simple use a [swingx jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs/swingx) then like this

```
JTextArea txtMSISDNList = new JTextArea();  
PromptSupport.setPrompt("01197585960,01197585961", txtMSISDNList);
```

Comment: Such an simplest way. Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: You are most welcome friend.

Comment: Your link is broken. Do you have an update for it?

Comment: Download the jar file here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingx161jar.htm

Comment: Unfortunately swingx isn't in development anymore, so use at your own risk (not sure if it's even compatible with Java 8). Important: No matter how trustworthy java2s.com seems, do NOT download jar files from anywhere except the original homepage EVER (you never know what's inside otherwise!)! You can still get the jar through [maven](https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;gav~org.swinglabs.swingx~swingx-all~~~~kw,versionexpand) (see "Download" column on the right).

Comment: If I am using above solution, the background of my Textfield goes grey in Mac.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand the question, [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) shows one way you can do this.

Comment: Thank's for a quick replay dear camickr