# How to fix text quality in Java graphics?

Tags: java, graphics

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TextRectangle extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        TextRectangle f = new TextRectangle();
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
        g2d.drawString("Why does this text look so ugly?", 30, 150);
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: result screenshot]

As you can see the letter spacing is uneven. Sometimes it's 1px, sometimes it's 2 or even 3 pixels. Another issue is the dot above 'i' is wider than the bottom part.

[image: problem details]

The same text written in a text editor looks much better. Do you know how to fix this problem?

My environment is Windows 8.1, Java 1.8.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with vector fonts?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://today.java.net/article/2005/07/21/lcd-text-anti-aliasing-fringe) can help

Comment: @MadProgrammer working link: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983384

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The graphics context uses integer metrics by default - meaning that rounding is applied to the location vectors of the glyph shapes.

You can switch to **fractional metrics** using:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
```

[image]

As you can see, no subpixel antialiasing was used (only gray antialias pixel). You can **enable subpixel antialiasing** for better legibility on LCD screens:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
```

[image]

There are 4 modes:

- `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB`: horizontally oriented RGB
- `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HBGR`: horizontally oriented BGR
- `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_VRGB`: vertically oriented RGB
- `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_VBGR`: vertically oriented BGR

I haven't found out where to query the appropriate value of the current display and orientation. Some displays can be tilted (landscape/portrait) or even rotated, requiring to redetect the mode when painting.

**EDIT**

I found something in the [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) book: apparently, the Java AWT Toolkit can provide appropriate rendering hints:

```
Map<?, ?> desktopHints = 
    (Map<?, ?>) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints");

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
if (desktopHints != null) {
    g2d.setRenderingHints(desktopHints);
}
// no need to set more rendering hints
```

On my system, this renders the text with fractional metrics and LCD HRGB antialiasing, same as with the code above. The hints on my system are:

- Text-specific antialiasing enable key: **LCD HRGB antialiasing text mode**
- Text-specific LCD contrast key: **120**

Comment: My main usage is video editing (with xuggler) where I'm in control to set image type on `BufferedImage` (for example `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`). So I guess it's independent from my system/monitor. Anyway, good to know how to obtain those hints.

Comment: How did you set the system wide LCD contrast. Is there some `-Dproperty=value` possibility?

Comment: Setting the hints from `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints")` works brilliantly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. My antialiasing was not greyscale but full level and it made the text like yours. It seems to be a problem that shows up if the image, to which the text is being rendered, contains an alpha channel. Limiting the image to RGB solved the antialiasing issue for me.