# how to add text below QR code using com.google.zxing libraby in JAVA

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I have generated QR code using `com.google.zxing` this library.
QRCode generations work fine but I want to display Data of QRcode below QRcode.

I want to generate QR code like attached below.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
        ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
        byte[] pngData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I Generated QR Code file and took in memory and then used Graphics Lib.
Using this Library could add Text to that Memory and saved it again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
   try {
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode("Hello world", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test.png");
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);     
        
        
                  
       final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path.toString()));
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
       g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(22f));
       Color textColor = Color.BLACK;
       g.setColor(textColor);
       g.drawString("Hello world", 15, 300);
       g.dispose();

       ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test45.png"));
        
                   
    } catch (WriterException | IOException ex) {
        
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here I have Provided complete code for generating QRcode with Text or not.

```
public byte[] generateQRCode(String data, Integer width, Integer height, String[] text) {

    try {
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);

        ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
        byte[] pngData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();

        //        If text is needed to display
        if (text.length > 0) {
            int totalTextLineToadd = text.length;
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngData);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);

            BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() + 25 * totalTextLineToadd, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = outputImage.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, outputImage.getWidth(), outputImage.getHeight());
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));
            Color textColor = Color.BLACK;
            g.setColor(textColor);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int startingYposition = height + 5;
            for(String displayText : text) {
                g.drawString(displayText, (outputImage.getWidth() / 2)   - (fm.stringWidth(displayText) / 2), startingYposition);
                startingYposition += 20;
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(outputImage, "PNG", baos);
            baos.flush();
            pngData = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        }

        return pngData;
    } catch (WriterException | IOException ex) {
        throw new ImtechoUserException(ex.getMessage(), 0);
    }
}
```

This will return Byte[] of  newly generated QR code with text or without text.

Comment: I tried this and the displayText looks blurry/distorted, so I added

```java
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

to make it look good.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537742/986966

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish Khokhariya thank you i do it withe your code
I am sorry I cant " feedback "  :
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
public BufferedImage getQRCodeWithText(BitMatrix qrcodeBitMatrix, String text) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(qrcodeBitMatrix);
    if (text.length() > 0) {
        int totalTextLineToAdd = text.length();
        int newWidth = image.getWidth();
        int newHeight = image.getHeight() + 10 * totalTextLineToAdd;
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics graphics = newImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, newImage.getWidth(), newImage.getHeight());
        graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));
        Color textColor = Color.BLACK;
        graphics.setColor(textColor);
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();
        int startingYPosition = image.getHeight() + 5;
        graphics.drawString(text, (newImage.getWidth() / 2) - (fontMetrics.stringWidth(text) / 2), startingYPosition);
        image = newImage;
    }
    return image;
}
```