# Java Text Field background text that disapears when clicked

Tags: java, textfield

As you can see in the title i dont know how to make a java text field with text in the background that disappears when you click on it.
So theres a textfield that says "username" and when u click on it the username disapears and you can type in your password. Is it possible to do this without a new class?

Comment: Which kind of textfield are you using (AWT, Swing, JavaFX, foofields...)?

Comment: jtextfield from javax.swing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java swing JTextField set PlaceHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213836/java-swing-jtextfield-set-placeholder)

Comment: can you do that without a new class?

Comment: `JTextField` doesn't have this feature, but if you don't want to subclass it, you may use `FocusListener` like the third answer in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion is to use swingx library and use JXTextField. so you can set the text using setPrompt method.