# NetBeans: Making a JTextField disapear

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, authentication, uitextfield

I'm trying to make an interface for a login/register app and I have, in the email box (jTextField) an example as text (example@gmail.com) but when I run my program when I click that box to write my email on it, I have to delete my set text to write what I want.

What I thought to do was to create 2 jTextFields, the one behind not editable and the one forward where I'd put my text. So there are two things I don't know how to do:

1. put the forward jTextField invisible so we can see the behind
   one
2. make the text on the behind jTextField disappear when I click the front one

Thanks for trying the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - placeholder on textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033600/java-placeholder-on-textfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can easily done with `FocusGained` and `focuseLost` events

```
private void txtEmailFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                     
    if (txtEmail.getText().equals("example@example.com")) {
        txtEmail.setText(null);
    }
}     


private void txtEmailFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                   
   if ( txtEmail.getText().equals("")) {
        txtEmail.setText("example@example.com");
    }
}
```